# php-fpm/xdebug status command does not work in laradock environment

Tags: php, xdebug-3

Can you help me get the php-fpm/xdebug status command to work?
I want to manually enable xdebug

[image]

mac info
[image]

docker version
[image]

docker compose version
[image]

xdebug has been turned on in workspace and php-fpm
[image]

php 7.4
xdebug 3.26

xdebug.ini conf

```
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

I tried changing remote_enable=1, but `php-fpm/xdebug start` also didn’t work.

Comment: Updating the configuration of xdebug3 also doesn’t work

```
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
xdebug.log_level=10
xdebug.log="/var/www/xdebug_logs/xdebug_docker.log"

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.cli_color=0

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

Comment: Please never add text as images, use formatted text (that makes it possible to search for it and copy+paste). You are calling an executable with a relative path, but you don't tell us in which directory you are.

Comment: you need to know which path